# apache child pid exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: apache-2.2, joomla, segmentation-fault

when I installed joomla I can't see the `index.php` and I get this messages in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[notice] child pid 3211 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

for activate the coredump, I follow the instructions in this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configure-apache-web-server-for-core-dump.html)

```
CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump # added this to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
mkdir -p /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
chown www-data: /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
chmod 0777 /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

but I don't see nothing in `coredumpdirectory`

```
ls /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
```

I can see the `localhost/administrator` of joomla but not `localhost/index.php`.

Comment: Did you request the page that causes the SegFault again after turning CoreDumps on?

Comment: @Ladadadada yes, I request the page

Answer (score 1):

I solved in joomla.
I activate the debug mode and apply

[image]

and deactivate debug mode, with this I fix the problem.

Comment: Please accept this answer if that's how you solved the problem.